# Weighted Quick-Union with Path Compression. How can depth of 4 can be achieved?

Tags: algorithm, union, analysis

I am trying to achieve a depth of 4 applying Weighted Quick-Union with Path Compression. Can you please help how to simulate it. I meant to ask sequence of union operations that that may result in depth of 4.

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, start with 32 elements. What happens if you pairwise link the elements, then pairwise link the roots of those new trees, then pairwise link the roots of those trees, etc.? I'll leave the rest of the details as an exercise, since this looks like a homework question.

Hope this helps!